# How do I make Windows 10 File Explorer search git repositories?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, git, windows-search

Windows released [a new update](https://archive.is/8NRmh) that means that git repos are no longer searched on File Explorer. How do I disable it?

Comment: Have you tried to set up Git repository locally (Clone the repository to your local machine)? Link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/contribute/get-started-setup-local

Comment: Yes I have done that and I still can't search it.